# Deduct result of one query from another SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have result of an SQL query as following:

```
Date | Pt_Cnt | Wardname | Division 
12/11| 23     | wd01     | Med 
12/11| 30     | wd02     | Surg 
12/11| 35     | wd08     | Surg
```

and I have a result from another SQL query for patients on leave as:

```
Date | Pt_Cnt | Wardname | Division 
12/11| 2      | wd01     | Med 
12/11| 1      | wd02     | Surg
```

I want the number of pt_cnt from the second query deducted from pt_cnt of 1st query. How can this be done in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
select a.date, a.pt_cnt-isnull(b.pt_cnt,0), a.ward, a.division
from (first query) as a
left join (second query) as b on a.date = b.date and a.ward = b.ward and a.division = b.divisionn
```

MySql:

```
select a.date, a.pt_cnt-ifnull(b.pt_cnt,0), a.ward, a.division
from (first query) as a
left join (second query) as b on a.date = b.date and a.ward = b.ward and a.division = b.divisionn
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `ifnull`

Comment: For sql server, replace ifnull by isnull

Comment: Since the question is for SQL Server, how about updating your answer.

Comment: Done, Thx for suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. This helped resolve my query.